# QGIS - Custom Icon to Show my Tool is Running?

Tags: qgis, python, toolbar, icon

I am running QGIS 2.6.1 (Brighton) I've some developers that have made some custom plug-ins, but our testers are complaining that they cannot tell when, if or what tool / plug-in is running. Is there a way I can have QGIS w/ python swap out the active icon to a different, alt. colored icon while the tool is active, and toggle it back to the default icon when the tool is turned off?

Comment: Are those tools supposed to be mutually exclusive? Should they even deactivate QGIS tools like 'Pan'?

Comment: In this case, yes because we've a very simple, specific set of tools that our field people are going to use. My customer has given me a list of icons that are to be removed / disabled. Even though we are running a very simple version of QGIS, with our own plug-ins providing the required GIS functionality, I need my (non-GIS) users to be able to look at the toolbar and see the proper tool lit up / greyed out / whatever so they know which tool they're using...

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/making-qgis-buttons-and-my-plugin-button-mutually-exclusive/132389#132389 By doing so, you could let users know what tool is active because it would remain pressed, just like QGIS lets you know the 'Zoom In' tool is active. Let me know if it helps.