# How to reflect the active state of a tool button in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a QGIS plug-in (3.0+) with a tool button (after selecting the toolbar icon you have to click in the map) and I can't set the icon active state (visual effect like the button is pushed in) like the info or the select button in the standard toolbars.

I create a new class based on QgsMapTool.

```
class PointTool(QgsMapTool):

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas
        ...

    def activate(self):
        super().activate()

    def deactivate(self):
        super().deactivate()

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        ...
```

Should I call some other method(s) in self.activate to change the active state of the icon in the toolbar?
The source code is available here: https://github.com/zsiki/arearatio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `initGui()`, just make sure your action is checkable:

```
action.setCheckable(True)
```

Your `run()` method should react according to the tool state. See this example: https://github.com/gacarrillor/NewLayersToTheTop/blob/master/newLayersToTheTop.py

Note that you might want to make QGIS tools and your tool mutually exclusive. See how to do it [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/making-qgis-buttons-and-my-plugin-button-mutually-exclusive/132389#132389).

Comment: @GermanCamillo, thanks for your help. I found a simpler solution to uncheck tool button in deactivate method. This way no need to collect all tool buttons. See my solution on GitHub.